# Organizing XPages and Custom Controls

Tags: xpages, designer

I have applied Categories to my Custom controls so that they are organized nicely in the Controls Selection Pane. But It would be great if they appeared under the same categories in the Application pane. My applications has probably close to 100 custom controls and it would save a lot of time if they could be categorized as well. Is there any way to be able to make that happen.

Comment: Adopt naming convention that suits you. We use prefixes to distinguish different use of CC (doc, view, edit, row, ui, ...) followed by "entity" (usually form it uses).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no. But you could move your custom controls from the database into a plug-in. Then they wouldn't pollute the CC section of a database, be re-usable across databases and might even load slightly faster.

Pro Tip: do not only categorize your controls, but also change the individual name spaces (default is xc), so when looking at the source code you can distinguish them instantly.

Only catch: some work required to move them to an update site.